# Capistrano 3: bundler not recognized when running custom shell command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano3

I'm having an issue implementing Capistrano deployment with jruby on RVM. I'm using PUMA as app server and that requires me to add capistrano3-puma in my Gemfile.
All in all, everything seems to work perfectly, my server's code got up-to-date fine from the git repo, and had the previous version of code archived nicely.
Except, every time I try to run shell command from Capistrano task,
such as, "bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start", for example, Capistrano can't seem to recognise bundle command.

My real case example is shown as below, when I run the above mentioned command in an overrided deploy:start method it return an error "bundle: command not found". I already tested the same command works fine, when I log on to the server via SSH and launch it from the app folder directly.

```
jruby 1.7.16.1 (1.9.3p392) 2014-10-28 4e93f31 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_65-b32 +jit [linux-amd64]
** Invoke deploy:start (first_time)
** Execute deploy:start
INFO[fc57a7d8] Running /usr/bin/env cd /var/appname/current &&  bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start on 192.168.2.6
DEBUG[fc57a7d8] Command: cd /var/appname/current &&  bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start
bind address: 
port: 22
host: 192.168.2.6
options: {:auth_methods=>["none", "publickey", "password", "keyboard-interactive"], :send_env=>[/^LANG$/, /^LC_.*$/], :user=>"root
", :forward_agent=>true, :logger=>#<Logger:0x14c7b324 @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x42c20b24 @filename=nil, @shift_age=nil, @dev=#
<IO:fd 2>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x51698ab9 @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x6812a170>, @mon_owner=nil>, @s
hift_size=nil>, @formatter=nil, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x1f24f571 @datetime_format=nil>, @level=4>}
DEBUG[fc57a7d8]         ***bash: bundle: command not found***
cap aborted!
Exception while executing on host 192.168.2.6: cd /var/appname/current &&  bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start exi
t status: 127
cd /var/appname/current &&  bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start stdout: Nothing written
cd /var/appname/current &&  bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start stderr: Nothing written
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@rails3.2.8/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status='
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@rails3.2.8/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:148:in `_execute'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'
```

here is my Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Deploy.rb

```
server '192.168.2.6', port: 22, roles: [:app], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@bitbucket.org:username/appname.git'
set :application,     'appname'
set :user,            'username'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0
set :shared_children,  []

set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }
set :default_shell, '/bin/bash -l'
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :staging
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/var/#{fetch(:application)}"

set :linked_dirs, %w{tmp/pids tmp/sockets log}
set :puma_bind,       "unix:///#{fetch(:deploy_to)}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{fetch(:deploy_to)}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{fetch(:deploy_to)}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{fetch(:deploy_to)}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{fetch(:deploy_to)}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, false  # Change to true if using ActiveRecord


namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc "Start the application"
  task :start do
    on "root@192.168.2.6", in: :sequence, wait: 5  do
      with :rails_env => fetch(:rails_env) do
        execute "cd #{current_path} && /bin/bash -l bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start"
      end
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end
```

staging.rb

```
set :stage, :staging
set :branch, 'master'
```

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'
gem 'roo','1.12.1'
gem 'jdbc-mysql', platform: :jruby
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter', platform: :jruby
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.2'

gem 'haml', '3.1.7'
gem 'puma'

gem 'devise', '2.1.2'
gem 'devise-async', '0.5.0'
gem 'cancan', '1.6.8'
gem 'simple_form', '2.0.4'
gem 'cocoon', '1.1.1'
gem 'inherited_resources', '1.3.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'mechanize', '2.5.1'
gem 'delayed_job', '3.0.4'
gem 'paperclip', '3.4.0'
gem 'spreadsheet', '0.6.4.1'
gem 'geocoder', '1.1.6'
gem 'whenever', '0.8.2'
gem 'american_date', '1.0.0'
gem 'money','5.1.1'
gem 'rets','0.5.1'
gem 'haversine','0.3.0'

group :assets do
  gem 'stylus', '0.7.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.3.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano',         require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: true
  gem 'capistrano3-puma', github: 'seuros/capistrano-puma',   require: false
end
```

any advice to help me resolve the problem would be very, very much appreciated.

## UPDATED

after editing the code as rubish suggested, 
now instead I issue the command like this => execute "cd #{current_path} && /bin/bash -l bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start"
now, it get to and is complaining about bundler under global rvm path. The exact new error looks like the following.

```
DEBUG[df47d6e1] Finished in 0.463 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
jruby 1.7.16.1 (1.9.3p392) 2014-10-28 4e93f31 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_65-b32 +jit [linux-amd64]
** Invoke deploy:start (first_time)
** Execute deploy:start
INFO[93744fc5] Running /usr/bin/env cd /var/appname/current && /bin/bash -l bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start on
 192.168.2.6
DEBUG[93744fc5] Command: cd /var/appname/current && /bin/bash -l bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start
bind address: 
port: 22
host: 192.168.2.6
options: {:auth_methods=>["none", "publickey", "password", "keyboard-interactive"], :send_env=>[/^LANG$/, /^LC_.*$/], :user=>"root
", :forward_agent=>true, :logger=>#<Logger:0x4c860e93 @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x7526fc24 @filename=nil, @shift_age=nil, @dev=#
<IO:fd 2>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x5273db92 @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x34547888>, @mon_owner=nil>, @s
hift_size=nil>, @formatter=nil, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x15b5438f @datetime_format=nil>, @level=4>}
DEBUG[93744fc5]         /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@global/bin/bundle: line 9: require: command not found
DEBUG[93744fc5]         /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@global/bin/bundle: line 11: version: command not found
DEBUG[93744fc5]         /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@global/bin/bundle: bundle: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token 
`('
DEBUG[93744fc5]         /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@global/bin/bundle: bundle: line 15: `  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BI
NARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding'
cap aborted!
Exception while executing on host 192.168.2.6: cd /var/appname/current && /bin/bash -l bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.
rb start exit status: 2
cd /var/appname/current && /bin/bash -l bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start stdout: Nothing written
cd /var/appname/current && /bin/bash -l bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start stderr: Nothing written
```

Comment: For your last problem, you need to make sure that you're invoking bundle exec from your app's directory so RVM can pick up ".ruby-gemset" and ".ruby-version" files otherwise it will use the global gemset which is something you really don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally RVM is initialized only in a login shell, so capistrano commands are unaware of RVM. Simply change your shell command to fix this:

```
# play nice with rvm
set :default_shell, '/bin/bash -l'
```

Comment: arhh, thanks @rubish
I have updated my code as per suggested. at least, the error has changed.
I instead did this => execute "cd #{current_path} && /bin/bash -l bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start"

DEBUG[93744fc5]         /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@global/bin/bundle: line 9: require: command not found
DEBUG[93744fc5]         /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@global/bin/bundle: line 11: version: command not found
DEBUG[93744fc5]         /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-
      
please reference to the full error in my updated question in the bottom.

Comment: @SarunSermsuwan It seems, bundler not recognized is resolved. Please mark this answer as accepted if it helped you solve the problem. Your update is a new problem altogether, please create a new question for it.

Answer (score 0):

So you're pretty much hitting some of the same issues I did when I made my RoR + JRuby + Puma + RVM app. I don't remember all the details but there are a few things that you need to do

1 - I had to use capistrano3-puma from git that was not broken:

```
gem 'capistrano3-puma', github: 'seuros/capistrano-puma'
```

2 - Include rails env + path on rake tasks:

```
 on roles(:db), in: :sequence, wait: 3 do
    within current_path do
      with :rails_env => fetch(:rails_env) do
        rake "some:task"
      end
    end
  end
```

3 - Finally - and this is the real messed up part since Puma doesn't read~/.bashrc to load RVM paths:

Put the loading of RVM paths in ~/.bash_profile also

There are a number of other things I had to do to get everything working but this should be the big stuff that's not implementation-specific. Also, don't forget to turn Puma into a service or you will have downtime.

Comment: thanks Srdjan. I have tried as per suggested.
with no luck, still the same error, but I keep on shuffling thing around to get Capistrano to see bundler

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your config files(`staging.rb`, `deploy.rb`)

```
set :rvm_map_bins, fetch(:rvm_map_bins).to_a.concat(%w{ puma pumactl })
```

capistrano-puma gem doesn't always map its bundler with rvm it seems.