# "bash: bundle: command not found" - cap aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3, puma

here is my *deployment.rb* file.

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

set :stage, 'production'
set :application, "gobgob-ror"
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:narhamah/gobgob-ror.git'
# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror'

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"

#set :user, "ubuntu"
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, "production"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :ssh_options, { user: 'ubuntu', :forward_agent => true, :port => 22, keys: ["#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/id_rsa"]}


# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true
server "xx.xx.xxx.xxx", roles: [:app, :web, :db], :primary => true

set :normalize_asset_timestamps, %{public/images public/javascripts public/stylesheets}
# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Start the application"
  task :start do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} bundle exec puma -b 'unix://#{shared_path}/sockets/puma.sock' -S #{shared_path}/sockets/puma.state --control 'unix://#{shared_path}/sockets/pumactl.sock' >> #{shared_path}/log/puma-#{fetch(:stage)}.log 2>&1 &", :pty => false
    end
  end

  desc "Stop the application"
  task :stop do
    on roles => :app  do
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} bundle exec pumactl -S #{shared_path}/pids/puma.state stop"
    end
  end

  desc "Restart the application"
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} bundle exec pumactl -S #{shared_path}/pids/puma.state restart"
    end
  end

  desc "Status of the application"
  task :status do 
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} bundle exec pumactl -S #{shared_path}/pids/puma.state stats"
    end
  end
end

after "deploy", "deploy:restart"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
```

Now I did `bundle exec cap production deploy`. And after huge log I got the below error.

```
DEBUG [cced60a1]        bash: bundle: command not found
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host <ip-snipped>: cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart exit status: 127
cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart stdout: bash: bundle: command not found
cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart exit status: 127
cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart stdout: bash: bundle: command not found
cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:restart
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host <ip-snipped>: cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart exit status: 127
cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart stdout: bash: bundle: command not found
cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart stderr: Nothing written
[arup@gobgob-ror (master)]$
```

Comment: I tried this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27389170/2767755) .. didn't work

Comment: Could you include the command you entered immediately before the error message? May help with context.

Comment: @onebree I did `cap deploy` after sometime .. I got the error when it tried `puma restart`...

Comment: Okay, just include that in your question body. I will point my friend to this, who knows capistrano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have now which resolved the issue. I got help from [Rustam A. Gasanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644810/rustam-a-gasanov) to make it working. Thanks a lot!!

**deploy.rb**

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

set :stage, 'production'
set :application, "gobgob-ror"
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:narhamah/gobgob-ror.git'
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.2.2@gobgob'
set :rvm_binary, '~/.rvm/bin/rvm'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror'

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"

#set :user, "ubuntu"
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, "production"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :ssh_options, { user: 'ubuntu', :forward_agent => true, :port => 22, keys: ["#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/id_rsa"]}


# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true
server "xx.xx.xxx.xxx", roles: [:app, :web, :db], :primary => true

set :normalize_asset_timestamps, %{public/images public/javascripts public/stylesheets}
# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Start the application"
  task :start do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} #{fetch(:rvm_binary)} #{fetch(:rvm_ruby_version)} do bundle exec puma -b 'unix://#{shared_path}/sockets/puma.sock' -S #{shared_path}/sockets/puma.state --control 'unix://#{shared_path}/sockets/pumactl.sock' >> #{shared_path}/log/puma-#{fetch(:stage)}.log 2>&1 &", :pty => false
    end
  end

  desc "Stop the application"
  task :stop do
    on roles => :app  do
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} #{fetch(:rvm_binary)} #{fetch(:rvm_ruby_version)} do bundle exec pumactl -S #{shared_path}/pids/puma.state stop"
    end
  end

  desc "Restart the application"
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} #{fetch(:rvm_binary)} #{fetch(:rvm_ruby_version)} do bundle exec pumactl -S #{shared_path}/pids/puma.state restart"
    end
  end

  desc "Status of the application"
  task :status do 
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} #{fetch(:rvm_binary)} #{fetch(:rvm_ruby_version)} do bundle exec pumactl -S #{shared_path}/pids/puma.state stats"
    end
  end
end

after "deploy", "deploy:restart"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
```

Last output which confirmed it works..

```
INFO [12d4a428] Running /usr/bin/env cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.2.2@gobgob do bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart on xx.xx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [12d4a428] Command: cd /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/current && RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.2.2@gobgob do bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/gobgob-ror/shared/pids/puma.state restart
DEBUG [12d4a428]        Command restart sent success
DEBUG [12d4a428]
INFO [12d4a428] Finished in 1.379 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
[arup@gobgob-ror (master)]$
```

Comment: But what did you do differently? It's not clear in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `bundler` gem is not installed on your server. It should be installed and the `bundle` executable should be available in `$PATH`.

Try executing the `bundle --version` directly on the server to ascertain that `bundler` is actually missing.

If that is case, install the `bundler` gem and you should be good to go. Or to actually keep things automated you can define a capistrano task to check if the `bundle` executable is available or not and install the `bundler` gem if it is not available. You can execute this task before the `bundler:install` task.

**UPDATE** : If you are using some ruby manager like `rvm` or `chruby` or anything like that, the `bundle` executable might not be available to your Capistrano deploy task. In that case you have to make sure your deploy task gets a login shell so that all those shell scripts are executed.

Comment: I am using `rvm`...... How should I make sure about you said *In that case you have to make sure your deploy task gets a login shell so that all those shell scripts are executed.*